# Sending data between PC and Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, sockets

I have been trying to send data from my Windows PC to my Raspberry Pi 3 for a python controlled speaker project. I am using TCP sockets which I don't know much about.

Client code (PC):

```
import socket


TCP_IP = '92.***.***.**'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()

print("received data:", data)
```

Server code (Raspberry Pi):

```
import socket
TCP_IP = "92.***.***.**"
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20 #NOrmally 1024 but we want a fast response
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
print("Connction address: ", addr)
while 1:
  data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
  if not data: break
  print("received data: ", data)
  conn.send(data) #echo
conn.close()
```

When I run this, it comes up with this error on Server.py:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
 File "/home/pi/Server.py", line 9, in <module>
   s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I have checked and rechecked and each of the IP addresses is the servers (Raspberry Pi's) IP address.

Comment: try to bind on all adress : `TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0"`  or `TCP_IP = ''`?

Comment: adress starting with `92.` is `Class A` [IPv4 addr](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=92.10.100.20&mask1=24&mask2=) , are you behind NAT ?

Comment: get your current IPv4 on RPi: `ip a show wlan0` (change wlan0 for your network interface card) , Get your IPv4 on windows : `ipconfig /all` and search your network interface card connected to the same network of your RPi. Then for Win client :  TCP_IP = `192.168.X.X` and for the RPi server : `TCP_IP = '192.168.X.X'` (note the same subnet)

Comment: I have tried TCP_IP = "0.0.0.0" and it didn't work. Also, I'm not sure what the other comments mean.

Comment: What is your error with TCP_IP="0.0.0.0" exactly ? TCP_IP_"0.0.0.0" must be ONLY on the server part !

Comment: Haven't tried it only on server. There is no error just a long time then it says timeout.